# Print 1 followed by googolplex number of zeros

Tags: algorithm

Assuming we are not concerned about running time of the program (which is practically infinite for human mortals) and using limited amount of memory (2^64 bytes), we want to print out in base 10, the exact value of 10^(googolplex), one digit at a time on screen (mostly zeros).

Describe an algorithm (which can be coded on current day computers), or write a program to do this.
Since we cannot practically check the output, so we will rely on collective opinion on the correctness of the program.

NOTE : I do not know the solution, or whether a solution exists or not. The problem is my own invention. To those readers who are quick to mark this offtopic... kindly reconsider. This is difficult and bit theoretical but definitely CS.

Comment: "Mostly zeros" is the understatement of the year. :-)

Comment: I wish the rep limit on closing questions was 10k or so.

Comment: The problem is in counting from 1 to Googolplex on a computer which cannot hold that number in its memory / storage in the expanded form.

Comment: Oh.. Is it off topic? How embarrassing..

Comment: `print “1 followed by googolplex number of zeros”` and grab a sandwich.

Comment: @Rajan: can you print 3 zeros, using only one bit of memory?

Comment: @Martinho bool f = false; while (true) { if (f) { print 0; break; } else { print 0; print 0; continue; }  something like this?

Comment: @9dan Ok, now try using that trick to solve this problem. Can your program fit in 2^64 bytes? (oh, you forgot to set f to true, nevermind that)

Comment: @Martinho you are right. as you said in your post this isn't a generation problem.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that you want to print to a screen. Trying to print that to paper would be a major environmental crime.

Comment: @Thilo: If printing each 0 to the screen costs a few femtowatt of energy (or similar order of magnitude), the whole print job will probably suck up all the energy in the sun and still be barely started. It will probably need all the energy in the universe and still not get done.

Comment: Nitpick: a watt is not a unit of energy, it's unit of power.

Comment: @Martinho: Thank you ... I got sloppy on that one :-)

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aoDXDgu7sRc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is impossible. There are more states (10^(10^100)) in the program than there are electrons in the universe (~10^80). Therefore, in our universe, there can be no such realization of a machine capable of executing the task.

Comment: Consider that you only need 8 electrons to store 256 states, though.

Comment: I think, this is not easy to prove impossible because we have infinite time.

Comment: "you only need 8 electrons to store 256 states" Assuming that you can store a single bit in an electron. Maybe you can store even more states. My sub-atomic physics-foo is too weak for that.

Comment: @Thilo: Yes, but `log_2(10^(10^100)) = 10^100 * log_2 10 ~ 10^100 * pi ~ 10^100 * 3 >> 10^80`. Therefore, it is still not possible on a binary computer. For it to be the case that `10^100 * log_b 10 < 10^80` it must be the case that `log_b 10 < 10^-20` so that `b` must be absurdly large. We won't invent a `b`-ary machine for absurdly large `b`.

Comment: Consider that you can store 10^(10^100) as just 11 characters in a string.

Comment: Jason: I think your logic is flawed. We don't need to save that many states in the computer at the same time. We can save one state at a time.

Comment: @Sam Dufel: You can store an infinite number of digits in a string: `pi`. Does not mean you can calculate with that representation, not even enough to do the loop's `lt` and `inc`.

Comment: @Rajan: The machine needs to be capable of being in at least `10^(10^100)` different states. I'm arguing that we will never have such a machine.

Comment: You don't need to be able to calculate with that representation.  Given that you can store an otherwise unstorable number in a very small string, you can break up the problem into a manageable size.

Comment: @Sam dufel: you mean, you will give a name to every single number from one to googolplex?

Comment: However, you will need to store at least the number of digits already output (or the number of digits left). For some of those there are nice short representations such as `0` or `10^(10^100)`, but how about all the states in between, in particular the very long prime numbers?

Comment: @Sam Dufel: You still need to enter `10^(10^100)` different states.

Comment: @Jason: Note that for `log_b 10 < 10^-20` it must be the case that `b > 10^(10^20)`. Again, we will never have a `b`-ary machine with `b > 10^(10^20)`. (Note that `b` is also greater than the number of electrons in the universe. In fact, it dwarfs it.)

Comment: @Jason: Damn, we need a bigger universe! (Natural corollary to "Damn, we need a bigger database")

Comment: @Thilo: Sorry, I had to think about this carefully overnight. The symbol that we refer to as `pi` is not storing an infinite number of digits. `pi` is merely a symbol that we attach very special meaning to but it in no way is storing the decimal representation of the real number that we oft associate with it. I could just as easily be from Indiana and say "let `pi = 3`." When we attach that special meaning to it, it is merely standing in place for a certain real number associated with circles that has an infinite non-repeating decimal representation but it doesn't capture that representation.

Comment: @Jason: Of course, it's entirely possible that you over thought this.

Comment: "`pi` is merely a symbol that we attach a special meaning to". And so is `10^(10^100)`. This was in reply to Sam's argument that we could store this insanely huge number with just 11 characters. Also see Marthinho comment about giving a (short) name to every single number from one to googolplex.

Comment: @Thilo: But my point is that we aren't storing it but rather `pi` and `10^(10^100)` are just representations.

Comment: @Jason: That is exactly the point I was making, too. They are representations in a format that cannot be directly used for computation. Furthermore, even if it was possible to perform calculations on these (without transforming them into bits for the computer), you'd still need a unique representation for each of them, the sheer number of which making that part impossible as well (that was Martinho's point).

Answer (score 5):

First of all, we note that 10^(10^100) is equivalent to ((((10^10)^10)^...)^10), 100 times.

Or 10↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑10.

This gives rise to the following solution:

```
print 1
for i in A(10, 100)
    print 0
```

Comment: +1 for reducing it to a well-researched problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function

Comment: As long as we can come up with a generator function for A(m,n) which can handle those numbers, we are done. However, I think we are not there yet :-).

Comment: @Rajan: We already have a function that can generate A(m,n). Supply it with infinite time and space, and this code will work. If you have less-than-infinite time or space, then you'll need to specify what those limits are.

Comment: @Anon - Let me edit the question to add that we do not have infinite space so as to keep the spirit of the original question alive.

Comment: @Rajan: With only 2^64 bytes (= ~10^300 unique states), the problem is not possible. The system needs to able to tell the difference between having printed 0 characters, 1 character, 2 characters...10^(10^100) characters. Without enough distinct states for every possible number up to there, the only possibilities are "an infinite number of zeroes" and "a finite (yet not sufficiently high) number of zeroes".

Comment: "With only 2^64 bytes (= ~10^300 unique states), the problem is not possible. " You could use external storage (which is like @9dan said "rather infinitely huge but fewer than googolplex").

Comment: @Thilo: If you have fewer than 10^(10^100) distinct states, the problem is still not possible.

Comment: @Thilo Isn't using external storage cheating the 2^64 constraint? If you can use as much external storage as you can, that constraint is just meaningless.

Comment: Why would it be cheating? If you can get that much storage (which is impossible in this universe), you'd want to use it ;-)

Comment: @Thilo: impossible? Not sure. The number given by Jason for the number of electrons (or particles or atoms or whatever) is the number in the *observable* universe, not the *entire* universe (if it even makes sense to say *entire* universe). I don't want to rule out the possible of that much storage "existing", for some definition of "existing".

Answer (score 1):

Here's an algorithm that solves this:

```
 print 1
 for 1 to 10^(10^100)
      print 0
```

One can trivially prove correctness using [Hoare logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic):

1. There are no pre-conditions
2. The post condition is that a one followed by 10^(10^100) zeros are printed
3. The cycle's invariant is that the number of zeros printed so far is equal to `i`

EDIT: A machine to solve the problem needs the ability to distinguish between one googolplex of distinct states: each state is the result of printing one more zero than the previous. The amount of memory needed to do this is the same needed to store the number *one googolplex*. If there isn't that much memory available, this problem cannot be solved.

This does not mean it isn't a computable problem: it can be solved by a Turing machine because a Turing machine has a limitless amount of memory.

Comment: kind of relies on the implementation being able to evaluate and store that huge number, though

Comment: Well, the OP asked for an algorithm description (or a program). And stated that we can't practically  check the output, so there's no need for implementations. :P

Comment: No it doesnt... python cant handle 10^(10^100)... and thats the point of the question.

Comment: @Rajan: Why wouldn't python be able to handle that number (given a machine with enough memory of course)? As far as I know there's no upper limits (other than the system's memory) to python's numbers.

Comment: Who said anything about python?

Comment: With current technology, we can have 2^64 bits of memory. Taking even many magnitudes more than this is not enough to hold that number. The challenge is to count to something which is difficult to hold in memory in the expanded form.

Comment: Martinho: What I wanted to say is that today's computers cant handle 10^googolplex, so the loop is out of the question. I understand your solution, but that is not the answer why I asked the question. It does not resolve the problem that i am thinking of.

Comment: @Rajan: Wrong. That's how many addresses you can map in a 64-bit system. The amount of memory available is not limited by such details. Eric Lippert has a good blog post on this topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx I'm not claiming we have access to log(10^googolplex) bits though.

Comment: "we can have 2^64 bits of memory" false. We have rather infinitely huge but fewer than googolplex external memory.

Comment: @Rajan: So, you're saying that today's computers cannot handle 10^googolplex and you want a program that handles it?

Comment: Yes... indirectly. We cant write a simple for loop... maybe an indirect way exists. Thats the reason why I asked this question.

Comment: @jonderry: If you cannot represent one googolplex in the observable universe, then the answer is that there isn't one.

Comment: @Martinho, I agree that what the asker is looking for is impossible.

Comment: +1 finally understood the point ("it isn't a computable problem"). Thanks.

Comment: @9dan: That's not what I said! I said it can be computed in a Turing machine. Problem is, a Turing machine is just an *abstract* machine with *infinite* memory. Whether it can be computed in our universe, I can't say. I can say that it can't be computed with 2^64 bytes of space.

Answer (score 1):

in bash:

```
printf 1
while true; do 
  printf 0
done
```

... close enough.

Comment: h.ahahae(10e100) Optimization : use `print 0000`, it'll do it in 1/4th the time...

Comment: @st0le - oh, there are optimizations.  e.g. you can get a lot of zeros in some short code with something like `xxd -b -g 0 -c 256 -l 256 < /dev/zero | tr -d ": ."` ... but it proves the point: in order to print those 0s, you need to give the computer space to count them: for 256 or 2^8 that means at least 8 bits or one byte ... for 10^(10^100) you have an unfeasible set.  I think my solution is as close as is possible given the constraints of the problem.

Comment: Um, guys? I don't think it makes sense to optimize an algorithm with a complexity of O(∞).

Comment: I claim the complexity is O(1)! *running time* is infinite, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

There definitely is a solution to this problem in theory, assuming of course you have a machine that is capable of producing that sort of output.  I'm pretty sure that a googolplex is larger than the number of atoms in the universe, at least according to what the physicists tell us, so I don't think that any physically realizable model of computation could print it out.  However, mathematically speaking, you could define a Turing machine capable of printing out the value by just giving it a googolplex-ish number of states and having each write a zero and then move to the next lower state.

Comment: True. Theoretically its a trivial problem if the number can be held in memory. However, I dont think the number of atoms/particles in the universe is so directly linked with this problem. I mean I can write a program rather easily to print out googol or googolplex. I am wondering where is the limit and why? Or is there a way to print out any number of digits?

Comment: @Rajan: The number of electrons is the universe is very relevant. The program needs to be in a certain number of states. If those states can't be represented in the universe, such a program is impossible.

Comment: @Jason : That sounds reasonable. I am almost convinced, but hoping there is a solution which somehow bypasses this constraint.

Comment: @Rajan: You can't bypass physics. Sorry.

Comment: @Rajan: really?  You "can write a program rather easily to print out a ... googolplex?"  I'm not so sure that you can, within your 2^64 bytes of memory limitation: 2^67 ~= 10^20.  I think I'd like to see such a program.

Comment: @Zac... we can represent 10^100 in memory by 101 bytes, with each byte representing a decimal number. By writing a simple module for doing addition/subtraction on this 100 element array as a single number (implementing carry over etc), we can count upto a googol.

To print out a googolplex, we need to print out googol number of zeros after a 1. Since we can count upto a googol as shown in the previous step, we can write out a 0 at every step and print out a googolplex in the process. We dont exactly need to store a googolplex in memory.

Comment: @Rajan, of course, you're right ... I was thinking about your main question.  To write a googolplex in base 10 we only need a googol states, or at least 333 bits.  I was not thinking clearly.

Comment: @Rajan: But to print 10^googolplex, you need to count up to a googolplex.

Comment: @Martinho: Yes... and thats heart of the problem. Can we, by some trickery, step around this constraint of having to explicitly represent googolplex in its full expanded form in memory in order to count upto it?

Comment: @Rajan: **NO**.. ͡҉҉ ̵̡̢̛̗̘̙̜̝̞̟̠͇̊̋̌̍̎̏̿̿̿̚ ҉ ҉҉̡̢̡̢̛̛̖̗̘̙̜̝̞̟̠̖̗̘̙̜̝̞̟̠̊̋̌̍̎̏̐̑̒̓̔̊̋̌̍̎̏̐̑ ͡҉҉

Comment: "I am wondering where is the limit and why?" The limit is exactly where you place it: 2^64 bytes = 2^67 bits ~= 10^300 distinct states.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

- The console window to which you are printing the output will have a maximum buffer size.
- When this buffer size is exceeded, anything printed earlier is discarded, and the user will not be able to scroll back to see it.
- The maximum buffer size will be minuscule compared to a googolplex.

Therefore, if you want to mimic the user experience of your program running to completion, find the maximum buffer size of the console you will print to and print that many zeroes.

Hurray laziness!

Comment: mine is lazier and more cross-platform :)

Comment: @Zac: True, but your program would never stop running (not on its own, anyway). Mine would stop after filling the console buffer, so from the standpoint of the *computer*, it's doing less work. ;)